# Passing a Swift protocol to an Objective-C pointer

Tags: objective-c, swift, compiler-warnings, swift-protocols, pointer-conversion

*Using XCode 10.1 / Swift 4.2.*

I'm trying to assign an object that conforms to a Swift protocol to an Objective-C pointer. The following code is a minimal example that compiles and works as expected, but it gives me the following warnings:

If assigning to a local variable: `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSObject<Animal> *__strong' with an expression of type 'id<Animal> _Nullable'`

If assigning to a stored property:
`Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSObject<Animal> *' from 'id<Animal> _Nullable'`

Any idea on how to address that warning without just silencing it?

**Swift code:**

```swift
@objc protocol Animal {
    var name: String { get }
}

@objc class Pig: NSObject, Animal {
    var name: String = "pig"
}

@objc class Cow: NSObject, Animal {
    var name: String = "cow"
}

@objc class Farm: NSObject {
    static func getAnimal(name: String) -> Animal? {
        // return some animal or nil
    }
}
```

**Objective-C code:**

```c
// This code returns a valid pointer to a Pig object
// that is usable in objective-c, but it also triggers 
// the warning described above
NSObject<Animal>* animal = [Farm getAnimalWithName:@"pig"];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify that every `Animal` implementer also implements `NSObject`'s interface: `@objc protocol Animal : NSObjectProtocol`

You could also change the type of the variable in ObjC to `id<Animal>`.

Comment: NSObjectProtocol was what I was looking for, it works great thank you.


I looked at the second option but run into issues if I change the type in ObjC to use `id` : `Assigning to 'id<Animal>' from incompatible type '__autoreleasing id<Animal> *'`. Adding `__autoreleasing` then becomes an issue with strong properties.